# How to create an onclick function that retrieves the object ID on the HTML and attach the ID onto the API to be fetched and used?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

i'm a beginner developer in javascript trying to make a website to impress recruiters. I've succesfully retrieve information from my API and used it on my website which took me ages to figure out. Now the next problem is how do i make an onclick event that gets the ID i hardcoded onto the specific movie poster on my HTML, to be used in javascript to change the API address and get the data for that specific movie.

Notes: i have a modal onclick to host all the movie data on that modal.

My Javascript and HTML is below.

HTML

```
  <div class="poster" onclick="toggleModal(); getimdbID()" id="tt4154796">
                <div id="imdbID">tt4154796</div>
                <img
                  src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc5MDE2ODcwNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzI2NzQ2NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
                  alt=""
                  class="poster__img"
                />
                <p class="movie__title">Avengers: Endgame</p>
                <p class="year">2019</p>
              </div>
```

Javascript

```
async function getMovie() {
    const movies = await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt4154796&apikey=4148fa0f`);
    const movieData = await movies.json();
const  { Title, Year, Runtime, Genre, Director, Actors, Plot, Awards, Poster, Metascore, imdbRating, imdbVotes, BoxOffice, } = movieData

document.getElementById('title').textContent = Title;
document.getElementById('year').textContent = Year;
document.getElementById('genre').textContent = Genre;
document.getElementById('runtime').textContent = Runtime;
document.getElementById('plot').textContent = Plot;
document.getElementById('director').textContent = Director;
document.getElementById('actors').textContent = Actors;
document.getElementById('awards').textContent = Awards;
document.getElementById('metascore').textContent = Metascore;
document.getElementById('boxoffice').textContent = BoxOffice;
document.getElementById('imdbRating').textContent = imdbRating;
document.getElementById('imdbVotes').textContent = imdbVotes;
document.getElementById('poster').src = Poster;
}


getMovie()



// ToggleModal

let isModalOpen = false;


function toggleModal() {
    if(isModalOpen) {
        isModalOpen = false;
        return document.body.classList.remove("modal--open");
    }
    isModalOpen = true;
    document.body.classList += " modal--open";
}
```

I've tried to create a function onclick to get the value of the ID onclick but that didn't work.

```
function getimdbID() {
    let x = document.querySelector("#imdbID").value
console.log(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you want your function to return the "tt4154796" thats contained within the div. If this is the case you'll want to use `document.querySelector("#imdbID").innerText`.

Since using .value is typically used to retrieve or change values entered into input fields.